# ¿Como activar la tecla enter en cada input de un formulario responsive cuando se esta visualizando desde el celular?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, responsive

Buen día, tengo un sistema web responsive en donde cuando estoy pc o laptop no tengo ningún problema con la tecla enter. Cada formulario esta compuesto de campos input la cual esta utilizando el eventos JQUERY entre uno de ellos es **keypress** detectando la tecla enter con el código ASCII.
Aqui un ejemplo:

```
<input type="text" id="fral_numcomproba" name="fral_numcomproba" class="form-control input-sm solo_numeros" />

$("#fral_numcomproba").keypress(function(e) { 
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which); 
        if(code == 13 && $(this).val()!=""){
            alert("detectar");
            $("#fral_numidentida").focus().select();
        }
    });
```

Mi problema es cuando estoy visualizando el sistema en el navegador del celular o de una table no se activa la tecla enter en el teclado de dicho dispositivo. Aquí el ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por su ayuda estaré muy agradecido.

Comment: Hago validación de los registros es por eso que cuando hago enter en un campo me ejecuta una validación mayormente utilizo ajax pero en este casi no lo puse.

Comment: puedes probrar con onkeydown y e.key = Enter

Answer (score 0):

Con el evento `keypress` tendrías para solucionar tu problema, te muestro un ejemplo con **Javascript puro** que fácilmente podrías pasarlo a **JQuery**

```
//accedemos al input y agregamos el evento keypress

document.querySelector('#fral_numcomproba').addEventListener ('keypress',function(e){
  validar(e);
})

//funcion para validar se  haya pulsado enter incluyendo dispositivos moviles

function validar(e) {
  let tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
  if (tecla==13) alert ('Has pulsado enter');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Los campos input tan dentro de una etiqueta `<form>` cuando llego al ultimo activa la tecla enter en el celular, así mismo si le quito la etiqueta  se activa el enter en cada input, la cuestión es que yo utilizo la función serialize() y validate() en cada formulario.
¿habrá una forma para que funcione sin necesidad de eliminar la etiqueta `<form>`?